# Open Internet Explorer using Visual Basic and re size the ie window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, button

Hey I have been stuck on this bug for a long time I hope someone can help,
so in my .NET program when you press a button a timer starts which opens up multiple Internet Explorer windows but the problem is that I want each window opened to be a different size which can be done by adding randomness to the size. But I am not sure how to do that.
PLEASE HELP!!!

this what i have so far

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "www.google.com")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code `Timer1_Tick` is in .Net

But, if you are looking for VBA solution , try something like this

```
  Sub IE()

        Dim oIE As Object

        Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        oIE.navigate2 "www.google.com"
        oIE.Height = CInt(Int((1000 * Rnd()) + 1))
        oIE.Width = CInt(Int((1000 * Rnd()) + 1))
        oIE.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

This link might help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hey also i was wondering whether u can add randomness to which website it will open choosing from google, yahoo , facebook, twitter?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using interop and USER32.dll

Let me give u an example in c#.

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    public IntPtr win_handle;

    void somefunction(){
            string ie_win_class = "IEFrame";
            string ie_win_nm = "New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer";
            win_handle = FindWindow(win_class, win_name);
            MoveWindow(win_handle, 600, 600, 600, 600, True);
     }
```

sorry, i don't have experience with VB. I hope this helped you.

links-

[MoveWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[COM Interop (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/6bw51z5z.aspx)